# Running unit test on Test Agent from Visual Studio: Logon Attempt failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, acceptance-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to set up a Test Controller and Test Agent to be used by developers when they run their unit tests from Visual studio. I have the TA and TC set up and connected to each other. I have created the testsettings file in a project and set the Test execution method to Remote Execution, pointed at the Test Controller. When I try to run a test on the TA i get the following out put in visual studio:

```
------ Run test started ------
Ignoring test impact data collector settings specified in the .TestSettings file.
Failed to queue test run 'user@MACHINE 2014-08-28 08:46:31': The server has rejected the client credentials.
The logon attempt failed
========== Run test finished: 4 run (0:00:17.353169) ==========
```

The test controller log is as follows:

```
V, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:31.215, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, User CORP\user is system, Admin, or controller user
I, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:31.215, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, A user has successfully authenticated to obtain the ControllerObject.
I, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:31.262, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, Testing LoadTestResultConnectString
W, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.411, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, Test of LoadTestResultConnectString failed: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
V, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.724, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Hello
V, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.724, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Hello
V, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.756, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, User CORP\user is system, Admin, or controller user
I, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.756, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Creating ControllerExecution for TestRun d7489f6d-4608-4b19-abf5-74d773cf3917
I, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.756, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerSpooledJob: creating spooled job for test run 'user@MACHINE 2014-08-28 08:46:31'
I, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:46.756, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Queuing TestRun d7489f6d-4608-4b19-abf5-74d773cf3917
V, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:49.494, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerObject.RequireAgentServiceUser: Agent: AGENT of environment [Default] trying to connect.
V, 2156, 23, 2014/08/28, 08:46:49.494, CONTROLLER\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: AgentHello from AGENT
```

I am not sure why I am getting this logon error when the TA and TC are talking to each other just fine. I think it could have something to do with the LoadTestResultConnectString but I have not been able to find much about it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to run a Load Test on VS 2015 when the controller/agent combo was still using the VS 2013 version of controller and agents.

Easy fix was to start the load test using VS 2013.